# Determine if SoapUI (ReadyAPI) is started via testrunner.bat or by the user (running in UI-mode)

Tags: batch-file, groovy, soapui, environment, ready-api

Is it possible to determine if SoapUI (ReadyAPI) is started

1. via testrunner.bat
2. by the user (running in interactive UI-mode)

---

I know that you can retrieve the current environment using this groovy script code:

```
def env = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.activeEnvironment.name
```

However I wonder what value this will return when running via the command-line (testrunner.bat) ; will it return the active environment from the test project, or will it be null/empty ?

**Update (use-case)**
The user case is that depending on the way the tests are run. In case of `testrunner.bat` I want to be able to set the environment to a fixed value. Else I want enable the user to select the environment manually.
Note that the some environment settings like EndPoints for each environment are defined a pre-defined XML file.

**Update (possible solution)**
@albciff
On the latest version from ReadyAPI (1.9.0), this does not work as you described.

- testrunner.bat returns `SoapUIProTestCaseRunner`
- running via ui returns `InProcessSoapUIProTestCaseRunner`

When using this code:

`def runner = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.getCmdLineRunner();
log.info "runner = [" + runner.getClass().getSimpleName() + "]"`

Comment: Would you please elaborate your use case? where do you want find that information and how that will help? testrunner is just utility to execute the tests. But UI is not necessarily for execution, can be used for designing the tests.

Answer (score 2):

A more easier way to detect this would be:

```
if (com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.isCommandLine()) {
  // todo
}
```

Found at [community.smartbear.com](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/Res-test-is-run-from-the-commandline-with-groovy/td-p/41181)

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no property inside SOAPUI to difference between how it's executed. In fact I test your proposal:

```
def env = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.activeEnvironment.name
```

And it returns `Default` for both cases (from UI and using `testrunner`).

A possible workaround to do so, it's for example to pass a project property parameter in the CLI of the `testrunner` execution; and then in your code check for this parameter to detect how the project is launched.

To pass a project property you've to use `-Pname=value`. So for example launch the `testrunner` using:

```
testrunner -r -I <path/To/yourProject.xml> -PrunningBy=testRunner
```

And then in your code you can get the property and check for this content to decide if it's running by `testrunner` or from the UI, something like:

```
def runningBy = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue('runningBy')

if(runningBy){
    // it's not null so is launched from testRunner
}else{
    // it's null, so is launched from UI
}
```

**UPDATE**

After reviewing the API seems that it's possible thought the follow method:

```
com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.getCmdLineRunner()
```

It returns `null` when executed from UI, instead when executed from `testrunner` it returns and instance of `com.eviware.soapui.tools.CmdLineRunner`.

So you can use something like:

```
def clr = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.getCmdLineRunner()

if(clr){
    // it's not null so is launched from testRunner
}else{
    // it's null, so is launched from UI
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work on my ReadyAPI version, see my updated comment. Can you please double check on this ?

Comment: in ReadyAPI version 2.7.0, it returns a com.smartbear.ready.cmd.runner.pro.**InProcessSoapUIProTestCaseRunner** instance when run from UI, and a com.smartbear.ready.cmd.runner.pro.**SoapUIProTestCaseRunner** when run with testRunner